# No keyboard and mouse on the Windows 7 installation menu

Tags: windows-7, usb, drivers, keyboard, mouse

Alright. I've been working on this for a week now, and I need to solve this.

So, here's my problem:

I have a Windows 7 USB I just formatted, GPT partition scheme, Fat32 format.
I then boot into the USB via my BIOS (specs below) and after the Windows 7 orb shows up, the "Install Windows" menu shows up. No mouse, no keyboard inputs, nothing.

I then go to create a custom NTLite ISO with the following drivers: ASMEDIA and the unofficial Windows 7 drivers.

I make the ISO, burn it, boot from it, same problem. No keyboard or mouse inputs.

Here are my specs:

Z390 motherboard with UEFI on it,
Logitech G900 mouse,
NPET gaming keyboard,
6 cores,
16 gigabytes of RAM.

The computer has already been in service for about 5 years, getting an upgrade last year, kept the motherboard.

If anybody finds possible drivers, please link them. This has been a problem for *3 weeks.*

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would try an older generic usb mouse and keyboard.  I keep one each plus an old ps2 around for these types of problems.  Probably a couple of bucks at a thrift store.  You can add the drivers for your particular hardware to your ISO but it is time consuming and involves editing your boot.wim and install.wim files.  A tutorial for doing that can be found searching online.  I don't think your motherboard has ps2 ports, but a cheap generic usb keyboard and mouse should get you started until you can get far enough along to install the newer keyboard and mouse.

Comment: Funny enough, I was using a plain USB keyboard and mouse, one from the 2000's to be particular. I am currently working on an ISO with a fuck ton of drivers (hoping one would work) so I could install Windows 7 normally. Another problem, they don't make PS/2 mouses anymore and I am not sure if I am even able to get one. But I will start looking, I will let you know if this does not work.

Comment: Just checked, my Z390 has no PS/2 ports, so the PS/2 option does not work. Any other suggestions?

Comment: just a generic usb keyboard and mouse.  one so common that windows automatically loads drivers for them.  Or look into editing those .wim files....

Comment: found a few, gonna try them out with my patched ISO.

Comment: or, just a thought, try a new iso file

Comment: im using official ISO's, i tried like 50 using a regular USB keyboard, all the same, no difference

Comment: Okay, if you can find, can you please link possible drivers below that could help my situation?

Comment: I got Windows 7 installed with a bunch of drivers, one of them worked! Hello from Windows 7!